# "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime" SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently getting this error and i am completely lost as to what the issue is. I tracked the error down to a view and completed a select * statement from it and i get that message. Now, the weird thing is is that this error has never appeared on this view before. It has always ran without any issues and nothings been changed so i am unsure as to what the issue is.

I cant show the data for security reasons but it holds 2 date fields that are

```
 datetime, not null
```

but i am not trying to change this data in anyway, i am simply just trying to select it.

The only other fields i thought it might concern are

```
decimal (38,20)
```

could this be the issue?

Sorry for the lack of information regarding the tables but i have literally tried everything from casting the fields to larger decimals, floats etc and still nothing.

It would be great if there was any small advice anyone could give that would possibly point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

If i do a

```
select top (1000)
```

query it works but any larger and i get that error

Comment: is there any data type casting or conversion inside the view?

Comment: Could you post what the view looks like? I’m betting your datetime field is joining to a non-datetime field.

Comment: Do u have where clause anywhere in the query ?

Comment: @AbdulRasheed did you see my update? why would it work with a 1000 limit but not work for everything

Comment: You should update your question with a view text. You can substitute table names with T1...Tn if you don't want to show your real table names. There is some join of type varchar = datetime or smth like this

Comment: May be some wrong data

Comment: Do you have any expression like DATEADD in your view? I can show you 100 examples of how it can be, but to find the error in YOUR case I need to see YOUR VIEW CODE

Comment: @calamities you were right! Thanks for the advice. I think someones been messing with the view code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using sql server version 2012 or higher, try use TRY_CONVERT function.
It goes like

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, ColumnName).
```

NOTE: It will return a NULL if ColumnName contains data which can't be converted to a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

i think there are some wrong date has been inserted in database, you need to use

`ISDATE()` sql function for same eg. like below in your select query

```
 (CASE WHEN ISDATE (your_date) = 1 
             THEN convert(datetime, cast([your_date] as char(8)))
             END) AS your_Date
```